# Echoing error message in the website from another file

Tags: php, html

I created a function that handles the duplication of data, if there is a duplicate it will display the error message, the error message is declared like this in the `save11.func.php`

```
$sql_section = mysqli_query($conn,"select *,COUNT(*) as count from schedule 
    natural join section 
    natural join strand
    natural join time 
    where strand ='$strand' and section ='$section' and schedule.timeID = '$daym' 
    and day ='m' and grade = 'Grade 12'") 
or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_section);
$count_s = $row['count'];
$times=date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_start']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_end']));
$sections = $row['section'];
$strands = $row['strand'];

$error_s = "<span class='text-danger'> 
<table width='100%'>
    <tr>    
        <td>monday</td> 
        <td>$times</td> 
        <td>$sections</td>
        <td>$strands</td>
        <td class='text-danger'><b>Not Available</b></td>                   
    </tr>
    </span>
</table>";
```

And it is echoed in the same file like this:

```
if (($count_t == 0) and ($count_r == 0) and ($count_s == 0)) {
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into schedule (timeID, subject, instructorID, day, room, strand, section, grade) VALUES 
    ('$daym','$subject','$ins', 'm','$room', '$strand', '$section', 'Grade 12')");  

    echo "<span class='text-success'>
    <table width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td>monday</td>
            <td>$time_t</td> 

            <td>Success</td>                    
        </tr>
    </table></span><br>";
}
    else if ($count_t>0) echo $error_t."<br>";
    else if ($count_r>0) echo $error_r."<br>";
    else {echo $error_c."<br>";}
}
```

But I want to echo the error message in my schedules.php so the user won't have to go back if the inputs are take they will stay at the same page and input another data..I tried this

```
header("Location:../pages/scheduling.php");
```

Yes it well redirect me to the page where the user will input but it wont display the error messages declare in the other file.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why do you collect data in that strange way?

Answer (score 0):

Is it right, that you would like to display an error message on another page then where it was given?

One solution for this is using sessions. So when the error message is generated, you can put it in a session like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["defineYourNameHere"] = $error
```

And then on the other page:

```
session_start();
$errorString = "";
if(isset($_SESSION["theNameOfTheSessionVariable"])
{
     $errorString = $_SESSION["theNameOfTheSessionVariable"]
}
```

When you do this the $errorstring is either blank, or it contains the error that you want to show.

The `if(isset($variable)){}` looks if the variable that you put in there exists, that prevents errors like that the variable is not defined.

Comment: I used the get statement to echo out the message, i thinks it's already fix thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, keep in mind that everyone could edit your error message if you use the get statement. So make sure you aren't using that variable for anything else then displaying a message! @dread